# Using an extend from a class or use composition

Tags: java

I have a abstract class called user and I'm wondering if i have to add another class that requires a user does it need to extend from the class below or do i need to reuse the user class via composition, all help is greatly appreciated.

```
public abstract class User implements Serializable { 
    protected String userName;
    protected String emailAddress;
    protected Date dob;
    protected Password password;

    // Initialisation Constructor
    public User(String userName, String emailAddress,
           int d, int m, int y,
           String cPW, String uEPW, int noTries){
      this.userName = username;
      this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
      this.dob = new Date(d, m, y);
    } 

    this.password = new Password(cPW, uEPW, noTries);
    // Assume that User also has ==>
    // 1. a toString() method,
    // 2. an equals() method, and
    // 3. appropriate set() and get() methods
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing to me, please clarify. It would help if you make it much more concrete -- show how you're trying to use User and how it's not working.

Comment: Note that another class can declare a User variable, but you can't have a `new User(...);` anywhere since you can only construct a concrete class. So it would have to be something like: `User myUser = new SomeConcreteUser(...);` where `SomeConcreteUser` extends from `User`.

Comment: Design decisions like this almost always come down to the individual use case.  But I think a question like this is off-topic for StackOverflow; [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) might be a more appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear why this class needs to be marked as abstract. An abstract class is one that cannot be instantiated, but you have written a constructor suggesting that it can?

Since an abstract class can't be instantiated on its own the only way it can be used is via inheritance.

In this scenario though, it would seem that your `User` class should not be abstract, and therefore other classes can simply use it via composition.

In general, prefer composition over inheritance where it makes sense, and if there is a need for inheritance, prefer to inherit purely abstract interfaces rather than classes containing implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is an "is-a" relationship. 
Composition is a "has-a" relationship.

So if the new class is for example, Admin - An admin is-a user so use inheritance. 
If the new class is something like UserAccount - use composition. The account is not a user but is associated with one.